# Python ArgParse

Tags: python, argparse

I want to use Python ArgParse to accept only certain inputs from the user.

So in below example let's say I want to accept 'type1/type2/type3' as argument only. Is that possible?

```
parser.add_argument('-t', '--type', type = str, help = 'type1/type2/type3')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`choices` argument](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#choices) to limit the input to a limited set of choices:

```
parser.add_argument('-t', '--type', choices=('type1', 'type2', 'type3'), 
                    help='type1/type2/type3')
```